# How to divide column automatically?

Tags: database, excel, text, organization

I have multiple txt files (close 1000) and I want to import to excel. I used text import wizard then choose fixed width, my question is how to use the same format for each file that I don't need to adjust everytime.

This is the example link : http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/bridge/nbi/1992/AL92.txt

This is the record format: http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/bridge/nbi/format.cfm

Comment: You can use either the VBA `Range.Parse` method, or the `Workbooks.OpenText` method and define the *FieldInfo* appropriately. If you have problems with your code, post back with your code, and an explanation of the problem with it.

Comment: You could also use the `QueryTables.Add` method.  In any event, record a macro while you do what you want, and then clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save you a bit of time I prepared the array (from the format web page linked above) for the querytables/import for you based on @RonRosenfeld's advice and quickly did a text file import (which I recorded).
Have to paste in here cause it is too big for comments. 
You would, of course, have to edit to suit.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\AL92.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(3, 15, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 24, 1, 18, 25, 4, 7, 1, 10, 2, 8, 9, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 4)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to know on what wrong it is in (.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False)

Comment: If you are getting an error on that line try getting rid of the BackgroundQuery:=False and see how that goes.

I just tested again with both and it worked as it yesterday.